# Python 2.7.10 Kivyにてon_key_up、_on_keyboard_up等が使用できない？

Tags: python, python2, kivy

Kivyにてこのプログラムを実行すると、

```
 TypeError: _on_keyboard_up() takes exactly 5 arguments (3 given)
```

と出てしまうのですが、何か間違っているところがあれば指摘お願い致します。
on_key_up、_on_keyboard_up等が使用できないのであれば、キーを押している間やまたはキーを離した後という事をKivy内で判定できる他の方法を教えていただければ幸いです。

## main.py

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '600')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock


sm = ScreenManager()
keyrpush = 0 #右キーが押されているか

class Player(Widget):
      pass

class FirstScreen(Screen):

     player = ObjectProperty(None)
     shots = ListProperty()

     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         super(FirstScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
         self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
                                             self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')
    if self._keyboard.widget:
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self._on_keyboard_up)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        print('My keyboard have been closed!')
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_up=self._on_keyboard_up)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print('The key', keycode, 'have been pressed')
        print(' - text is %r' % text)

        if keycode == (275, 'right') :
            keyrpush = 1
            print self.player.center_x

        if keycode == (276, 'left') :
            print "左"
            self.player.center_x = self.player.center_x - 1

        if keycode == (273, 'up') :
            print "上"
            self.player.center_y = self.player.center_y + 1

        if keycode == (274, 'down') :
            self.player.center_y = self.player.center_y - 1
            print "下"

        if keycode == (122, 'z'):
            if len(modifiers) == 1:
                if modifiers[0] == "shift":
                    print "アイテムショット"
            else:
                print "通常ショット"

        return True

    def _on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print('終わり')
        return True

    def update(self, dt):
        pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = FirstScreen()
        sm.add_widget(FirstScreen(name="first"))
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return sm



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

## main.kv

```
<player>:
canvas:
    Rectangle:
        size: 21,38
        pos: self.pos
        source: 'img/player.png'

<Shot>:
    size: 10, 30
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.siz
<FirstScreen>:
    player: player
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: 500, -42.5
            size: 303,640
            source: 'img/frame.png'
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        pos: 350, 120
        text: "/1000"
        font_name: 'fonts/Optical A Normal.ttf'

    Label:
        font_size: 20
        pos: 350, 172.5
        text: "0"
        font_name: 'fonts/Optical A Normal.ttf'

    Label:
        font_size: 20
        pos: 350, 220
        text: "未実装"
        font_name: 'fonts/NotoSansCJKjp-Thin.ttf'

    Label:
        font_size: 20
        pos: 275, 120
        text: "100"
        font_name: 'fonts/Optical A Normal.ttf'

    Player:
        id: player
        center_x: root.center_x - 87.5
        center_y: 150
```

## 使用環境

```
macOS 10.13.2
pyenvのPython 2.7.10（Kivy on iOS等を使用する為）
```

Comment: ドキュメントざっと見た感じでは Keyboard の [`on_key_up`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html?highlight=request_keyboard#kivy.core.window.Keyboard) は `on_key_down` と違って keycode しか受け取らないので引数の数が違って怒られてるように見えます．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ご回答させていただきます。
Kivyのon_key_upイベントに結び付くメソッドの引数として
keyboardとkeycodeのみとなります。つまり、text, modifiersを指定する必要はありません。

なので
`def _on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):`
ではなく
`def _on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode):`
となります。

APIのリファレンスなどを参考にするとよいかもしれません。
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。早速その通りにしたところできました！今度からはもう少しきちんとドキュメントを読んだ上でわからないところがあった場合質問するよう心がけます。